# How to download an image with Nodejs, when its URL doesn't contain the file extension?

Tags: node.js, stream, request

I'm building some web scraper in Nodejs. One of the things that scraper can do, is download images. All was good, until i tried to scrape a site, whose images do not contain the file extension in the url, like: https://example.com/images/someimagewithoutextension

This is some of the code, from the small library i'm using, to download and save images:

```
 options.encoding = null

request(options, (err, res, body) => {
if (err) {
  return onError(err, done)
}

if (body && (res.statusCode === 200 || res.statusCode === 201)) {
  if (!path.extname(options.dest)) {
    options.dest = path.join(options.dest, path.basename(options.url))
  }

  fs.writeFile(options.dest, body, 'binary', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return onError(err, done)
    }

    if (typeof done === 'function') {
      done(false, options.dest, body)
    }
  })
}
```

So, when the image URL lacks extension, i get an error like this:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\nodescraper\images\somefilenamewithoutextension'

When i console.log() the 'body' of the response, i get some Buffer array(therefore i can't check for the mime-type or something similar), and from what i understand, this indicates a stream. When i remove the encoding:null from the request configuration, i get a set of characters, but node virtually crashes.

How could i save such images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### ENOENT

From [node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors):

> ENOENT (No such file or directory): Commonly raised by fs operations to indicate that a component of the specified pathname does not exist — no entity (file or directory) could be found by the given path.

Also, this error can happen if the filename contains any [restricted characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words) such as **?**, so it is recommended to remove or replace those characters to make sure your app runs without any errors. Check the [sanitize-filename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-filename) package on the npm.

#### Detect extension

The HTTP [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) response header contains [mime-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) of the response body. So you can use it to detect the file extension you are downloading. For example, if you get the content-type of **image/jpeg** the file extension can be **.jpeg**.
There is also a bunch of [libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mime) on the npm that can convert mime types to file extensions.

#### Complete example

```js
const { writeFile } = require('fs');
const { extension } = require('mime-types');
const { basename, extname, join } = require('path');
const request = require('request');
const sanitize = require('sanitize-filename');

const dest = join(__dirname, 'images');
const url = '<URL>';

request({ url, encoding: null }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error || response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode >= 300) {
        console.error('Request failed!');
        return;
    }

    let fileName = join(dest, sanitize(basename(url)));
    if (!extname(fileName)) {
        const contentType = response.headers['content-type'];
        const ext = extension(contentType);

        if (ext) {
            fileName += `.${ext}`;
        } else {
            console.error('Cannot detect file extension!');
        }
    }

    writeFile(fileName, body, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log('done');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i already solved my problem. So yes, there were two issues: getting the extension from the content type, exactly as you did; Removing illegal chracters(i used a library for it). It all works now :D